# How to add a first solvation shell in a simulation

Tags: vasp

Can someone guide me on how to add a first solvation shell of water around a particular cation (Na+) , for a single point calculation purpose? is it physically meaningful to add water just around the cation? do i need to add a Cl- ion as well?

Comment: For single-point energy calculations, you can place how many ever number of water molecules around the Na+ ion and then do the calculation.